# CareKit/ResearchKit NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, researchkit, carekit

I am getting the following error when trying to return ORKOrderedTask.timedWalk

CODE:

```
    static func walkingAssessmentTask() -> ORKTask {

    return ORKOrderedTask.timedWalk(withIdentifier: "Walking", intendedUseDescription: "", distanceInMeters: 5, timeLimit: 20, options: [])

}
```

ERROR:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'timed walk distance must be greater than or equal to 1 meters and less than or equal to 10000 meters.'

Highlighted Error Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on an older version of ResearchKit. Try downloading most recent ResearchKit. Your initializer for timedWalk will have one more parameter called 'includeAssistiveDeviceForm'.